# Find closest value in a big list

Tags: c#, .net, binary-search

There are solutions e.g.

```
list.OrderBy(item => Math.Abs(number - item)).First()
```

or

```
list.Aggregate((x,y) => Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number) ? x : y);
```

which are `O(N)` at best.

The solution bellow should be faster than a sequential scan on a large list. It is more performant to sort the list first (`O(NlogN)`) and then use `List<T>.BinarySearch` for each query. The performance for `k` queries is `O((k+N)logN)`, in comparison to `O(kN)` of the previous methods.

The question is did I implement it correctly?

```cs
private decimal FindClosestLevel(IReadOnlyCollection<decimal> collection, decimal value)
{
    var list = collection.ToList();
    list.Sort();
    var index = list.BinarySearch(value);
    if (index > 0)
    {
        return list[index];
    }

    index = ~index;
    if (index >= list.Count)
    {
        return list[list.Count - 1];
    }

    if (index <= 0)
    {
        return list[0];
    }

    var val1 = list[index - 1];
    var val2 = list[index];
    return val2 - value > value - val1 ? val1 : val2;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The question is did I implement it correctly?

Do you have any test cases?

Anyway:

### The algorithm

> It is more performant to sort the list first (O(NlogN)) and then use List.BinarySearch for each query.

I would agree with that, it's a good approach, but it's not what the code does. What it actually does is *for each query*, sort the list and then binary search in it. There is no advantage then, each query would take O(N log N) that way, O(kN log N) for k queries, so worse than the O(kN) approach.

### The interface

That also means that the interface should be different. You cannot do this in the way you planned to it through the interface `decimal FindClosestLevel(IReadOnlyCollection<decimal> collection, decimal value)`. Even if you put a precondition on this that the collection must have been sorted already, you cannot binary search an `IReadOnlyCollection` directly (copying it into a list would make the query O(N) again, so that's a dead end). You need all queries in one place, to handle them all in one go after sorting the collection *once*, only then does the approach actually reach the O((k+N) log N) that you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Which interface do you suggest? I suppose I have to use `List<T>`, so I could call `.Sort` and `.BinarySearch` on it. https://pastebin.com/F1YV6ks5 Is it good like that?

Comment: @nop You can make that interface work, but the `Sort` has to be removed in order to reach the time complexity target. There should be only one call to `Sort` in total (so it would be called somewhere else in your program, in a place that you have not shown, that is between the list being made and the queries being performed), not one for each query.

Comment: thanks. Well, either way my list is sorted by default, e.g. 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000.

Comment: @nop even better, then you don't need any call to `Sort` and you're down to O(k log N) for only the binary searches